# How can i get specific value from JSON string

Tags: apex

//main code

list ls = memberMap.get(Rz.Roles__c);
String JSONString = JSON.serialize(ls);

//Debug code

[{"attributes":{"type":"Work_Team_Member__c","url":"/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Work_Team_Member__c/a81W00000008gIsIAI"},"Id":"a81W00000008gIsIAI","Member_Employee_ID__c":"63","Member_Name__c":"Test1","Member_Role__c":"Account Representative – General (Secondary)","Work_Team_Master__c":"a80W00000009DodIAE"}]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: i have a json output string in the above given format (mentioned under Debug code section), i need to get specific value from the string ie Member_Employee_ID__c

Comment: while i am trying to deserialize the string it is goving me the error :Invalid conversion from runtime type List<ANY> to Map<String,Work_Team_Member__c>